# Blender is limiting the amount of vram being used then crashing?

Tags: rendering

Does blender limit amount of vram that can be used. I ask this because I have a radeon pro with 8GB of ram but blender will never use above around 4gb[image]

Comment: Blender should not artificially limit the amount of VRAM used, as far as I know. If it crashes it is either a bug, or your scene is too big for your hardware. If no more memory is used it is either full, unavailable, or not required.

Comment: I have a radeon pro wx5100 and I am not sure if blender is able to access all of my vram. I have checked that my pc can take all my ram through gpu-z and windows 10 system diagnostcs. So I am pretty sure blender is limiting the use of ram. Is there a solution to this?